# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start on Eclipse

Tags: jsp, tomcat

i am trying to run a web based jsp application but tomcat server does not start.it starts sometime but suddenly stops again.this is the log i got.please can somebody help me about this?i have tried many things for two days but could not get a solution

i am trying to run a web based jsp application but tomcat server does not start.it starts sometime but suddenly stops again.
THis is the log i got.please can somebody help me about this?
i have tried many things for two days but could not get a solution

```
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.45
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 14 2019 22:21:25 UTC
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.45.0
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_221-b11
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\EE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\EE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\EE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xbootclasspath:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\lib\servlet-api.jar
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;D:\2.Tools\Programming\eclipseEE;;.]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 800 ms
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.45
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5075)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1222)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-example]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-example]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [net.javaguides.employeemanagement.controller.EmployeeServlet] and [net.javaguides.employeemanagement.web.EmployeeServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/register] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:339)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2395)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2060)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1220)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.MultiThrowable: 2 wrapped Throwables: [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-example]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:935)
    ... 8 more

Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.MultiThrowable: 2 wrapped Throwables: [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-example]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:935)
    ... 8 more

Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 12, 2019 9:45:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]`enter code here`
```

Comment: Why is `C:\Users\User\Desktop\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar` listed in the boot classpath? Tomcat comes with the API jars you should be using.

Comment: please what should i do?

Comment: Find why it's on the classpath of your project or when launched and remove it from there.